# What is a "good" desktop sharing software for doing training? Also, what else can it be used for?

Tags: remote-desktop

**WOW:** Just used the software, it's exciting to think of all the possible uses... Which got me thinking, what is software like this good for? For example: Presentations, training, tech support, usability test monitoring, etc. Clearly it's not good for remote computer administration for example.

---

**Original_Question:** Looking for software that allows 2 or more people to see each others desktops remotely in parallel, any suggestions?

---

**My_Choice_So_far:** [Mikogo](http://www.mikogo.com) appears to be the best solution, which was suggested by [Pratish](https://serverfault.com/users/56946/user56946):

(Here are my notes/links so far.)

### Mikogo (Win, Mac... and Linux via [Wine](http://www.winehq.org)):

- [It’s free (for personal use)](https://mikogo.zendesk.com/entries/21201473-Do-I-need-to-pay-for-Mikogo-)
- [Features](http://www.mikogo.com/product/features/)
- [Security](http://www.mikogo.com/product/security/)
- [Video Tutorials](http://www.mikogo.com/support/video-tutorials/)
- [User Guide](http://www.mikogo.com/support/user-guide/)
- [Server Download](http://www.mikogo.com/download/windows-download/)
- [Client Download (exe)](https://join.mikogo.com/download/download.aspx?code=MIKOGO_WIN_EN&lang=EN&et=2)

**NOTE (1):** Also, of interest, although I don't understand why, Mikogo appears to installs on Win-XP without ADMIN rights.

**NOTE (2):** If you have any comments about Mikogo, or a better solution -- please let me know, thank!!

Comment: what OS is on the desktops?

Comment: WIN-XP to WIN(?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.mikogo.com/

Pratish

Comment: **@Pratish:** Thanks, thank does appear to be the best solution! (It's free 100%, secure, participant cannot view nor control another’s screen without the explicit consent of the other participant in question, 1-many, presenter hand off, and more... very cool, thanks!)

Answer (score 3):

I use TeamViewer v 3.0.  Quick install of client, quick setup, quick access.  Switch sides, chat, and really very, very fast on the video (unless you're watching motion picture over it).  Easy to understand for a client that is a newbie.

TightVNC is the best techie tool, however.  But it takes a little more to set up.  And it has more capabilities.

**Edit**

@Blunders

In answer to your comment below, and to your MiKogo reference, added to your question above.  I took a look at reviews of the two programs (Mikogo and Teamviewer).

1. [TeamViewer Review](http://www.software-today.com/teamviewer-review) (See bottom
   of this page for Mikogo review)
2. [Second TeamViewer Review](http://downloadsquad.com/2008/10/09/lees-favorite-apps-teamviewer)

**Mikogo** takes the winners flag on features. It allows one to host multiple simultaneous clients, and blocks clients from seeing parts of presenters screen.  And also lets one change presenters.

**TeamViewer** is more of a help desk tool. The major difference with TeamViewer is that neither host nor client must register. One does not even have to install the software. Just go to the site, and run it from there, without an install.

TeamViewer can be run from a flash drive. You can take it with you, and use as host from any computer.  Also, you can have your client install it as a service, so you can reboot their system remotely, log back in, and continue removing malware (I've had to do this).

**Edit**

@Blunders

I do not have personal experience with either of the other products you mention, in your recent posts.  Good point that TeamViewer is pay for commercial use.  I don't use it commercially.  Also, I agree that interfaces after version 3.0 were somewhat cumbersome.  That's why I have been using an older version.  It was simpler to use on both sides.

I'm going to take a look at both the products you mentioned.  The only reason I recommended TeamViewer is because I have a friend that is sooo pneumatic, and the person was able to use it. (Well, and for the other reasons mentioned above - it will run from a flash drive, and does not require visiting a web page).

Comment: **@Mike:** Thanks for the reply, so far I like Mikogo better, any reason why that's not a better solution? I've updated my question with info on it. Again, thanks!!

Comment: **@Mike:** Thanks, I'll just mark your answer as selected. So, I looked at TeamViewer, and to start, their product selection model is confusing; or at least it was to me. That said, I called them and was able to figure out that **TeamViewer's "free" version is for non-commercial use ONLY.** Mikogo is free for both non-commercial AND commercial, which was the core reason I kicked TeamViewer off my list. Again, thanks!

Comment: **@Mike:** PS - In rolling out using this with clients, one had used a product named http://www.yugma.com -- do you have any personal experience using it, and any idea how it compares to Mikogo?

Comment: **@Mike:** Here's a description from Yugma about the pay version: "Yugma Pro gives you even more - desktop sharing, plus the power to fully interact and collaborate with others. **Use annotation & whiteboard tools, share mouse and keyboard control, change presenters instantly and more.** " -- All the features listed in **BOLD** are free with Mikogo.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to install a free VNC server/client on each machine. www.tightvnc.com . They would then login to each machine to see that machine.

a free two way non setup way to see someone elses computer is http://www.crossloop.com/ . However I believe this is only good for 1 to 1 at most.

Now instead of having multiple machines login you can broadcast your desktop using http://www.tightvnc.com/projector/ . However this only works on the LAN I believe.

Comment: **@PHGamer:** Thanks for the reply, so far I like Mikogo better, any reason why that's not a better solution? I've updated my question with info on it. Again, thanks!!

Answer (score -2):

It all depends on what "good" means here. 
For desktop sharing, there are three types of service: hosted, software and appliance.

Most hosted solutions (such as Mikogo and Yugma) are priced per month or per year.  It is easy to use. But it relies on the third part sever to host the service. Well, the obvious dangers of passing data through a third party is clear -- essentially you're agreeing to put all of your company's data in the cloud.

For software (such as Teamviewer), it is more secure. But software usually has high up-front cost – you need to have a dedicated computer to host it to avoid disruptions from other applications and extensive time to setup and maintain.

The best approach is to deploy an appliance behind your own firewall to have a secure private cloud. Appliance has low upfront cost because it comes as a complete hardware and software bundled and pre-configured package. And there is no monthly fee. It is easy to deploy (plug-and-play) and maintain, as most of appliances have self-updating functions.
The leading vendors are Bomgar and RHUB.

http://web-conferencing.findthebest.com/compare/25-54/Rhub-Web-Conferencing-vs-Mikogo

http://web-conferencing.findthebest.com/compare/7-25/TeamViewer-vs-Rhub-Web-Conferencing

Comment: Let me guess, you work for Rhub?